# When does convergence of subsequences implies convergence of sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ and $(a_{n_i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent subsequence (we know that such exists because $X$ is compact). Denote by $l$ its limit. My question is:

> Suppose that, for every integer $k \geq 0$, the subsequence $(a_{n_i+k})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)$ converges to $l$. Is it necessary that $(a_n)$ also converges to $l$?

I think that this is true, but I could not prove it playing around with the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit. Any help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it's false

Comment: "Indirectly" I think, as "Exodd, it's false too. What's "Indirectly"? If all succession would be convergent, the known theorem were that and not  that every sequence contains a convergent subsequence. I do not think this question is difficult to prove.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. Define a sequence $(a_n)$ by
$$
a_n = n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor}
$$
i.e. the difference between $n$ and the largest power of $2$ less than it. Then the subsequence along powers of $2$ converges trivially, and any displacement of this subsequence also converges, but the entire sequence has arbitrarily large terms.

EDIT: I forgot the condition that the subsequential limits have to be the same. This is easily corrected though by multiplying by a sequence that goes to zero slowly. Take for instance
$$
a_n = \frac{n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n)\rfloor}}{n}
$$

Comment: did you mean $⌊log_2 (a_n)⌋$ or $⌊log_2(n)⌋$?

Comment: My bad, I have corrected it.

Comment: The question says that the shifted subsequences all have to converge to $l$. It doesn't look like they do in this example.

Comment: Whoops, that is indeed right. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Your conjecture is false.

Construct the original sequence in batches, where the $n$th batch consists of 
n zeroes followed by a single 1, that is, the sequence is 010010001... Suppose now your subsequence picks off the first zero in each batch. For each fixed k the translated subsequence will eventually be zero, but the sequence itself does not converge.